# What is the next step in solving the time derivative of expectation value of the momentum of a particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

So this question is a direct follow on from [my last question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/629957/am-i-doing-this-right-finding-the-time-derivative-of-expectation-value-of-momen)

I am trying to get an expression for $\frac{d\left<p\right>}{dt}$.

I have my working out below, which was thanks to the [Anonymous Physicist](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/629966/285973)'s help, (not to mention all the patient people in the mathematics chatroom) I have got to this expression:
$$
i\hbar
\left(
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
\frac{-i\hbar}{2m} \dfrac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} + \frac{i}{\hbar}V \Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}
}dx
+
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
\Psi^* \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}
}dx
\right).
$$

And now I'm stuck. What can I do about
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
\Psi^* \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}
}dx
$$

In particular how to deal with $$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}?
$$
With the $\partial t$ in play I don't know how solve the integral...

As before, I really would appreciate **hints** to get me moving in the right direction more than an outright solution.

### My working so far

We are given $\left<p\right>$ in the text, which is determined by computing $\frac{d\left<x\right>}{dt}$ and multiplying by $m$.

Lets just start with what we know:
$$
\left<p\right> = \int{\Psi^*\left[-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right]\Psi}dx.
$$

So taking the time derivative,
$$
\frac{d\left<p\right>}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\int{\Psi^*\left[-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right]\Psi}dx.
$$

We probably should at this point pause, and listen to Ted, ([and RobJohn](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57654132#57654132)).
So take out the constants before going any further.
We get,
$$
-i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
        \left(
            \Psi^*
                \left[
                    \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
                \right]
            \Psi
        \right)
        }dx.
$$

> [(1) Since the variables t and x are independent, you can bring the time derivative into the integral. You can also use the derivative product rule to get two terms in the integral.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/629966/285973)

Bringing the time derivative into the integral, gives us
$$
-i\hbar \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi^*\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right]\Psi}dx.
$$

Then differentiating with the product rule yields,
$$
-i\hbar \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
\frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}+ 
\Psi^* \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}
}dx.
$$

Now we have two terms in our integral, let's split em up.
Let's consider the left handside first,
we have
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
\frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}
}dx.
$$

By Schrödinger this can become,
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
\left(\frac{-i\hbar}{2m} \dfrac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2} + \frac{i}{\hbar}V \Psi^*
\right)
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}
}dx.
$$

Expand to get,
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
\frac{-i\hbar}{2m} \dfrac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}+
\frac{i}{\hbar}V \Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}
}dx.
$$

So, just to review, our full problem can be written as,
$$
i\hbar
\left(
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
\frac{-i\hbar}{2m} \dfrac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} + \frac{i}{\hbar}V \Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}
}dx
+
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
\Psi^* \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}
}dx
\right).
$$

Comment: Answered here in an additional comment https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/629957/am-i-doing-this-right-finding-the-time-derivative-of-expectation-value-of-momen/629966?noredirect=1#comment1416461_629966

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I doing this right? Finding the time derivative of expectation value of momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/629957/am-i-doing-this-right-finding-the-time-derivative-of-expectation-value-of-momen)

Comment: Yes Yes it does, I didn't know you could do that (swap the order of derivatives), so thankyou!